# selectedvaluechanged of combobox is not accessible to the user control vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, user-controls, event-handling

I have looked everywhere for an answer that I can wrap my brain around. In Visual Studio 2008 using VB.net, I have created a user control `VendorCombo` with one `ComboBox` `cbVendor`.  The `ComboBox` list is filled with a query from the mysql database.  All that works as planned.  When I put the user control on the form I am building, I want to use the `VendorCombo` events to trigger a function since I can't directly use the events of the embedded `ComboBox`.  The `ComboBox` event I want to use is the `SelectedValueChanged` but it is not exposed to the user control in the design form and you can't select the underlying `cbVendor` `ComboBox` from the designer.

I have looked for a good tutorial on the issue and no luck.  Can anyone point me to a tutorial or article that explains how to expose `ComboBox` events to the user control so I can then select the `SelectedValueChanged` event on the form from the user control?

Comment: If the UC has but one control on it, why not forego it and just use the CBO on the form.  Otherwise, you will have to raise the event again from the UC, but that is a bit of recreating the wheel.

Comment: I have a sql sub attached to the control that populates the list.  I have several areas in the project that require the exact combo box so my thinking was to create a custom box that is reusablle

Comment: I resolved the issue and will post how I made it work

Comment: Is there anyway to add a tutorial to this site?

Comment: you can add your own  solution here only

Answer (score 0):

you can use EventHandler or delegate for propating your combobox event to the page/window where usercontrol is used.

There is good answer is provided by user3641053. I would suggest it is the good answer and for getting better idea for EventHandler and Delegates u can googled around.

One link for understanding of  Delegates is as below.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30458/Delegates-in-VB-NET